# How to change startup layout from main.xml to another layout in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android, is there any way to change this startup layout. actually application is already developed and later I implemented login layout for this, now how can I change startup layout to login layout?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear enough for us to help you. How can an application could be developed without any layout. Please, be more specific, and add some code samples.

Comment: I clearly mentioned I want to change startup layout from main.xml to login..I don't know what you not understand in this :D

Answer (score 2):

Change your AndroidManifest.xml and add to the activity you want to start this:

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Of course, change the LAUNCHER category to DEFAULT in the activity that actually is launching on start.

Hope it help :)

Answer (score 1):

Any layout can be applied to any Activity by passing it to `setContentView()`.  Somewhere in the Activity you want to change, the line `setContentView(R.layout.main)` exists; you need to change this to point to whatever other XML layout file you wish to use.

HTH

Comment: that's the answer you're looking for